# How to reset the terminal under Cygwin?

Tags: terminal, cygwin, reset

Under Linux, I can clear terminal output with a simple `reset` from the command line. Under Cygwin, it appears `reset` does not work:

[image]

I also tried `reset 0` and `reset 1` with no joy. And I even tried the native Windows' `cls` command with no joy.

Cygwin appears to lack ***any*** useful documentation:

```
$ man -k reset
reset: nothing appropriate.

$ man -k terminal
terminal: nothing appropriate.

$ man reset 1
No manual entry for reset
No manual entry for 1
(Alternatively, what manual page do you want from section 1?)
```

How do I reset the terminal from the command line when using Cygwin? What is missing from the command above?

---

A bug report was filed with Cygwin for this issue: [Bug 19195: The Cygwin terminal does not respond to either 'reset' or 'cls'](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19195).

Comment: The proposed dup isn't a dup as it **does not** explain how to **reset** the terminal which is what the OP asked for (the dup explains how to clear the terminal - which is **not** the same thing)

Answer (score 7):

#### Under Cygwin, it appears reset does not work

- You are running a non Cygwin version of `reset`.
- You can confirm this by running `where reset` in a command prompt.

Notes:

- `c:\windows\system32\reset.exe` is **Remote Desktop Services Reset Utility**

  [image]
- The output you show in your question looks like it is from this version of reset (and not the Cygwin version).

---

#### Cygwin PATH setup

If you have installed the `ncurses` package (see below) then you need to make sure your Cygwin `PATH` has the Cygwin elements **before** the Windows elements (this should happen automatically when Cygwin is installed).

Example cygwin path:

```
DavidPostill@Hal /f/test
$ echo $PATH
.:/home/DavidPostill/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/apps/Calibre
```

---

#### Cygwin reset

The Cygwin `reset` is part of the `ncurses` package and is linked to `tset`.

Parameters to `tset` are optional.

You can determine this is on your system using:

```
which reset
```

On my system:

```
DavidPostill@Hal ~
$ which reset
/usr/bin/reset

DavidPostill@Hal ~
$ ll /usr/bin/reset
lrwxrwxrwx 1 DavidPostill None 8 Jul  1 08:14 /usr/bin/reset -> tset.exe
```

Cygwin `clear` is also part of `ncurses`. I have `cls` aliased as follows:

```
alias cls='clear'
```

Notes:

- You can always find out what packages contain particular cygwin commands using [Search Packages](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi).
- `clear` and `reset` have slightly different behaviour:

  - `clear` clears the visible part of the `mintty` display. The scrollback buffer remains as is.
  - `reset` sends the terminal *initialization string*. In the case of `mintty` this clears the visible part of the display and removes the scrollback buffer.

---

#### How do I check if ncurses is installed?

To see if a package is installed use `cygcheck -l ncurses`.

- `-l package` -  list contents of package (or all packages if none given)

```
DavidPostill@Hal /f/test
$ cygcheck -l ncurses
/usr/bin/captoinfo
/usr/bin/clear.exe
/usr/bin/infocmp.exe
/usr/bin/infotocap
/usr/bin/reset
/usr/bin/tabs.exe
/usr/bin/tic.exe
/usr/bin/toe.exe
/usr/bin/tput.exe
/usr/bin/tset.exe
/usr/share/doc/ncurses/ANNOUNCE
/usr/share/doc/ncurses/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/ncurses/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/ncurses/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/ncurses/README
/usr/share/man/man1/captoinfo.1m.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/clear.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/infocmp.1m.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/infotocap.1m.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/reset.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/tabs.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/tic.1m.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/toe.1m.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/tput.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/tset.1.gz
```

---

#### What is included in the ncurses package?

```
2015-05-18 21:00           0 usr/bin/
2015-05-18 20:58           0 usr/bin/captoinfo -> tic.exe
2015-05-18 21:00        9747 usr/bin/clear.exe
2015-05-18 21:00       52755 usr/bin/infocmp.exe
2015-05-18 20:58           0 usr/bin/infotocap -> tic.exe
2015-05-18 20:58           0 usr/bin/reset -> tset.exe
2015-05-18 21:00       14355 usr/bin/tabs.exe
2015-05-18 21:00       67091 usr/bin/tic.exe
2015-05-18 21:00       15379 usr/bin/toe.exe
2015-05-18 21:00       15379 usr/bin/tput.exe
2015-05-18 21:00       19475 usr/bin/tset.exe
2015-05-18 20:58           0 usr/share/doc/
2015-05-18 20:58           0 usr/share/doc/ncurses/
2015-05-18 20:58       13750 usr/share/doc/ncurses/ANNOUNCE
2015-05-18 20:58        2529 usr/share/doc/ncurses/AUTHORS
2015-05-18 20:58        1408 usr/share/doc/ncurses/COPYING
2015-05-18 20:58      549943 usr/share/doc/ncurses/NEWS
2015-05-18 20:58       10212 usr/share/doc/ncurses/README
2015-05-18 20:59           0 usr/share/man/man1/
2015-05-18 20:57        2919 usr/share/man/man1/captoinfo.1m.gz
2015-05-18 20:57        1201 usr/share/man/man1/clear.1.gz
2015-05-18 20:57        6976 usr/share/man/man1/infocmp.1m.gz
2015-05-18 20:57        1594 usr/share/man/man1/infotocap.1m.gz
2015-05-18 20:59          39 usr/share/man/man1/reset.1.gz
2015-05-18 20:57        2288 usr/share/man/man1/tabs.1.gz
2015-05-18 20:57        5995 usr/share/man/man1/tic.1m.gz
2015-05-18 20:57        1883 usr/share/man/man1/toe.1m.gz
2015-05-18 20:57        4540 usr/share/man/man1/tput.1.gz
2015-05-18 20:57        4971 usr/share/man/man1/tset.1.gz
```

Source [ncurses: Terminal display utilities (installed binaries and support files)](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fncurses%2Fncurses-5.9-20150516-1&grep=reset)

Comment: Actually, `reset` sends the terminal *initialization string*, and does not know anything specific about the scrollback buffer.

Comment: @jww It's a Cywin command You need to run it a Cywin shell **not** a cmd prompt.

Comment: @jww Run `which reset` in Cygwin shell.

Comment: OK, so I got back to this. `libncurses` and `libncursesw` ***are*** installed on my *Cygwin-i386* installation. I had to install `libncurses`. When I run reset, I now get ***`-bash: reset: command not found`***. On my *Cygwin-86_64* installation, only `libncursesw` is available. It was already installed, and it results in ***`Invalid parameter(s)`***. Both result in ***`which: no reset in`*** even though I have verified `libncurses` is installed via the setup programs.

Comment: Please read the second part of my answer. You need to install `ncurses`

Comment: @jww libncurses is a **library** used when building programs that use `curses`. `reset` is a **program** that is part of the `ncurses` package.

Comment: @jww do you have a file `/usr/bin/reset`? what is the output of `which reset`? What is it about my answer and the comments you don't understand?

Comment: @David - yes, ncurses is installed. If this god forsaken project had a bug reporter, I would report the problem (and the many other problems I have encountered trying to perform simple tasks). But they don't, so I'm just going to keep closing and opening terminals. Its easier and less aggravating.

Comment: @jww I still think some **other** `reset` is being executed. That's why I keep asking for the output from `which reset`!!

Comment: @jww and the output from running `where reset` in a normal **cmd prompt**.

Comment: @jww if you **really** want to report this as a bug (which I don't think it is as it's working for me and every one else who has tried to help you) then see instructions for doing so at https://cygwin.com/problems.html

Comment: @David - Ah, don't let that page fool you. I traversed that page (and a few others) when trying to report their buggy GCC. [There is ***no*** bug reporter](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-06/msg00664.html). Just a lot of misdirections and run around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25494/discussion-between-davidpostill-and-jww).

Comment: On my Cygwin, `type reset` and `which reset` report  `/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/reset`.   I don't know what `C:\Windows\system32\reset.exe` is, but it's clearly the source of the `Invalid parameter(s)` / `RESET { SESSION }` messages.

Comment: @scott. Can you right click on the file and see what `properties` > `details` says about the file? I don't have it and I think the OP probably did. He went away and we never tracked down what it was.

Comment: @scott are you running a flavor of Windows server? It looks like that includes reset.exe

Comment: @DavidPostill: No, just plain Windows 7 Professional (OEM).  `C:\Windows\system32\reset.exe` is [Remote Desktop Services Reset Utility](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ij7L.png).

Comment: @scott. Thanks, I will add that to my answer as well. I suppose that is the same as in Windows Server. I'm running Windows 7 home premium and I don't have that file. By the way, do you have `ncurses` installed?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Well, I'm a little embarrassed to say that I'm not sure, but I don't have `clear`, `cls`, `tput`, or `tset`, so I guess the answer is "No".

Comment: @Scott OK. Just checking. It explains your `which reset` output. Thanks for your help. It's enabled me to polish the answer some more ;)

Answer (score 3):

This cleans the screen and the scroll back buffer, both on mintty
and on console:

```
echo -e "\033c"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `clear` - it should do what you want.

Edit: It's part of the `ncurses` package, not installed by default.

Comment: `clear` results in `-bash: clear: command not found`. (I tried earlier; my apologies for not including it with the question).

Comment: Strange. I have `/usr/bin/clear` on my 32bit Cygwin installation.

Comment: If you don't have `clear` then maybe try `cls`?

Comment: @Ramhound - well, I didn't realize `clear` was a part of `ncurses`. Installing it is a viable solution though. About `cls` - my bad, I seem to be out of touch with Cygwin - I have `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\cls` so `cls` works fine for me in `bash`. OP might still *try* it, but you're right that it's more of a guesswork at this point and thus no-good of an answer.

Comment: @MikeFitzpatrick `clear` is **not** the same as `reset`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround solution if you don't yet have ncurses installed and thus 'clear'.
(**added note**- and as david postil has pointed out, the following will only work if you are running cygwin the old fashioned way via cygwin.bat i.e. `cd \cygwin<ENTER>`  `cygwin<ENTER>` ) the cygwin.bat file doesn't launch mintty, so it's launching it the old fashioned way, and you can then do `cmd /c cls`.

Comment: That does not work either. +1 to Cygwin... These guys really need to test their stuff.

Comment: @jww `cmd /c cls`  works for me and should work for you.  Any  executable in the PATH works and cmd.exe is in the path. What error are you getting?

Comment: @barlop `cmd /c cls` does absolutely nothing in a `mintty` terminal running `bash` (the default setup inn Cygwin)

Comment: @DavidPostill very interesting, thanks for pointing that out.  I think i'll move to mintty. Cygwin still comes with c:\cygwin\cygwin.bat which doesn't launch mintty.  So the old fashioned way is still kind of default. But I see your point that the start menu shortcut now launches cygwin via mintty. I have just changed my cygwin.bat to launch mintty(batch can be more convenient than the start menu)..  And indeed, cmd /c cls doesn't work from there.

Comment: @barlop Cywin should have installed a "Cygwin 64 Terminal" icon in Programs > Cygwin (`mintty` is in the base package). Shortcut is `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -`. The final `-` invokes a login shell.

Comment: @DavidPostill yes I can see that. I have it there too, there's nothing different about my installation. I did/do understand what you have been saying. As I said. I have up till now launched cygwin via the batch file.  As i'm often in cmd.exe anyway. The cygwin.bat that it comes with doesn't launch mintty. Though i've just now updated cygwin.bat to launch mintty

Comment: OK, so I got back to this. `libncurses` and `libncursesw` ***are*** installed on my *Cygwin-i386* installation. I had to install `libncurses`. When I run reset, I now get ***`-bash: reset: command not found`***. On my *Cygwin-86_64* installation, only `libncursesw` is available. It was already installed, and it results in ***`Invalid parameter(s)`***. These are side-by-side installations in different directories, so they are not cross-pollinating. Quite frustrating... And thanks for your help.

Comment: @jww Please read the second part of my answer. You need to install `ncurses`

Comment: @jww libncurses is a **library** used when building programs that use `curses`. `reset` is a **program** that is part of the `ncurses` package.

Comment: @David - it is installed. Both the narrow and the wide versions of the library.

Comment: @jww http://i.imgur.com/1mtbCrn.png    the library might come automatically but expand utils and choose ncurses

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin added `reset` to its repertoire of commands sometime around December 2015. It was around when [The Cygwin terminal does not respond to either 'reset' or 'cls'](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19195) was filed. Or maybe, it began working as expected.

If you don't have reset, then rerun the package setup program and update everything.